# Convertir de JSON a string

Tags: android-studio, json, string

Esta función forma parte de una factura.
Cuando la factura me aparece me despliega es un JSON yo quisiera que se viera la lista de productos asi

producto - precio

producto - precio

producto - precio, a diferencia lo que me muestra es 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
public String ProductosFacturas() {

    float montoTotalf = 0;

    int productsize = ctOnGo.getProductArraylistsize(1);

    //Crear Array de productos del carrito para pasarlos al servidor como pedido completado
    JSONObject Pedido = new JSONObject();
    JSONArray PedidoD = new JSONArray();
    JSONObject PedidoDL = new JSONObject();

    String pCode;
    String pName;
    Integer pQty;
    float pPrice;

    try{
        for (int j=0;j< productsize;j++){
            pCode = ctOnGo.getProducts(j,1).getProductCode();
            pName = ctOnGo.getProducts(j,1).getProductName();
            pQty = ctOnGo.getProducts(j,1).getProductQty();
            pPrice = ctOnGo.getProducts(j,1).getProductPrice();

            PedidoDL = new JSONObject();
            PedidoDL.put( "barcode", pCode );
            PedidoDL.put( "nombre", pName );
            PedidoDL.put( "cantidad", pQty );
            PedidoDL.put( "precio", pPrice );
            PedidoD.put( PedidoDL);

            montoTotalf = montoTotalf + pPrice;

        }
        Pedido.put( "Factura", PedidoD);


    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
    }

    return Pedido.toString();
}
```

Comment: Pero no entiendo, ¿si tus datos ya se supone que vienen organizados en el JSON, ¿para qué los metes también en un `Map`?

Answer (score 0):

Creo que el texto lo vas a mostrar enalgun texview entoces podrias usar un metodo que use la respuesta que te da ProductosFactura que ahora debe retornar un el JSON Pedido

```
public JSONObject ProductosFacturas() {

float montoTotalf = 0;

int productsize = ctOnGo.getProductArraylistsize(1);

//Crear Array de productos del carrito para pasarlos al servidor como pedido completado
JSONObject Pedido = new JSONObject();
JSONArray PedidoD = new JSONArray();
JSONObject PedidoDL = new JSONObject();

String pCode;
String pName;
Integer pQty;
float pPrice;

try{
    for (int j=0;j< productsize;j++){
        pCode = ctOnGo.getProducts(j,1).getProductCode();
        pName = ctOnGo.getProducts(j,1).getProductName();
        pQty = ctOnGo.getProducts(j,1).getProductQty();
        pPrice = ctOnGo.getProducts(j,1).getProductPrice();

        PedidoDL = new JSONObject();
        PedidoDL.put( "barcode", pCode );
        PedidoDL.put( "nombre", pName );
        PedidoDL.put( "cantidad", pQty );
        PedidoDL.put( "precio", pPrice );
        PedidoD.put( PedidoDL);

        montoTotalf = montoTotalf + pPrice;

    }
    Pedido.put( "Factura", PedidoD);


} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.show();
}

    return Pedido;
}


public void pedidoPrint() {
     JSONObject js = ProductoFactura();

    try {
        JSONArray mostrar = js.getJSONArray("Factura");
        for (int i = 0; i < mostrar.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject objeto = mostrar.getJSONObject(i);
            String precio = objeto.getString("precio");
            String produtcto = objeto.getString("nombre");
            //AQUI YA PUEDES SETEAR CADA VALOS A UN TEXTVIEW
            texviewPrecio.setText(precio);
            texviewProducto.setText(producto);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Tu metodo principal va a crear el JSON y el segundo metodo va a mostrar el texto ya legible

Comment: lo mostrare en un textview, podrias explicarme un poco mejor... disculpa!

Comment: he editado la respuesta completa

Comment: ya lo compredi, pero ahora no me muestra en los texview, estoy intentando algunas cosas

Comment: debes usar los textview definidos por ti,

Comment: Si eso estoy intentando... solo que el codigo es algo confuso porque de alli lo llevo a otro lado y es donde muestra

Comment: en otra clase? el metodo void es publico asi que lo puedes usar en otra clase

Comment: sigue sin mostrarse!!!

Comment: pon el metodo donde los mostras

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84237/discussion-between-andrea-valentina-and-igmer-rodriguez).